# How can I install ubuntu in VMware workstation in windows 8?

Tags: vmware, windows-8

I bought a new sony vaio laptop.

I found that I cannot dual boot in this system (model sve15136cns). When I try to use it on a Virtual machine (VMware) it suddenly shuts down.

Comment: Any errors while boot up?

Comment: you need to enable "Virtualization" in your BIOS setting. shutdown your laptop, then press "Assist" button and select BIOS setting from list. enable "Virtualization" and press <F10> to save changes and follow installation in vmware.

Answer (score 0):

This video tip gives you an overview of how you can install Ubuntu 11.10 on VMWare Workstation 8

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bieM-FNsERs)

I hope its what`s your looking for, Win8 basic is the same as win7